# separate and count emojis in python list

Tags: python, list, count, emoji

I want to count the occurrences of Emojis in a list in python.

Assuming my list looks like this
li = ['', '', '']

Counter(li) would give me {'': 1, '': 1, '': 1}

But I would like to get the **total** amount of emojis aka {'': 3, '': 2, '': 1}

My main issue is how to seperate large chunks of continous emoji into single list entries. I tried with replacing the beginning "\U" with " \U" so i could then simple split by " " but it does not seem to work.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can flatten you list into a single string using `join` and then apply `Counter` to that:

```
Counter("".join(li))
```

results in

```
Counter({'': 3, '': 2, '': 1})
```

or maybe a more memory efficient way is

```
counter = Counter()
for item in li:
    counter.update(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count the emojis by iterating on the characters of each string:

```
from collections import Counter

li = ['', '', '']

count = Counter(emoji for string in li for emoji in string)

print(count)
# Counter({'': 3, '': 2, '': 1})
```

---

@Dan gave a different answer just before me, which he sadly deleted since then, so I reproduce it for <10k users who can't see it:

```
Counter("".join(li))
```

I thought it might be less efficient because of the creation of the joined string, but I did some timings with small and larger lists up to 10 000 000 items, and it appears that his solution is consistently 30 to 40% faster.

Comment: Oh, I'm very surprised it is faster. I'll undelete. I can't imagine why it would be better though. Your looks like a single linear pass through the elements of the list, mine looks like 2 passes though it :/ maybe it lets the Counter hash table choose assign larger amount of space upfront?

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure either... I'll try to look at it later.

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to use the fact that counters implement addition:

```
>>> li = ['', '', '']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sum(map(Counter, li), Counter())
Counter({'': 3, '': 2, '': 1})
```